# How can I construct an extended metadata for a service provider?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml, opensaml

I have tried constructing a standard metadata which includes details regarding ACS url,Entity ID,authnRequest needs to be signed,nameid format,acs binding.
But I also need to construct an extended metadata for the same app which includes details like which attributes need to be mapped with saml attribute = IDP Attribute name.

I was referring to below link for which all attribute need to be populated in extended metadata.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19854-01/819-5209/gbsue/index.html
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19854-01/819-5209/gbvkb/index.html

Can anyone please guide me if they have any references to an open source repo or codebase which has implemented this stuff?